# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when use getParameterValues in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, indexoutofboundsexception

Here is is my HTML .....

I take one input for count how many input .. and then highest four entry can be given....

```
 No Of Members: <select name="member" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">Select</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>


       </select>

 <table class="table table-bordered">

                <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentid" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Student ID"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Email"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cgpa" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter CGPA"></td>
                    <tr/>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentid" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Student ID"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Email"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cgpa" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter CGPA"></td>
                    <tr/>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentid" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Student ID"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email3" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Email"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cgpa" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter CGPA"></td>
                    <tr/>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="studentid" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Student ID"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Email"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cgpa" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter CGPA"></td>
                    <tr/>


                </tbody>
            </table>
```

My Servlet

At first i take member no at a int type variable.. and then all the four field in four different array by getParameterValues.

```
  try{
            int member=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("member"));
            String stdID[]=request.getParameterValues("studentid");
            String name[]=request.getParameterValues("name");
            String email[]=request.getParameterValues("email");
            String cgpa[]=request.getParameterValues("cgpa");

            for(int i=0;i<=member;i++){

                System.out.println(stdID[i]+name[i]+email[i]+cgpa[i]);
            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

When  i run this code and select No member (4) and fill all the field and then press submit....

In my console below errors show

[image]

How can i solve this ? any idea ?

Comment: Btw for your third row, you have typo for name="email3" - <td><input type="text" name="email3" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Email"></td>

Comment: Yap... It was a typing mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   for(int i=0;i<=member;i++){
```

to

```
   for(int i=0;i<member;i++){
```

why have you changed the email to email3 in the third entry?